# Net Core 3.1, Firebird 2.5 and FB.EF 7.5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I currently have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and I'm using FirebirdSql.EntityFrameowrk.Core.Firebird v7.5.0.

When trying to update the database from a simple migration with a primary key and a string column

```
public class TB_CUSTOMER
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_CUSTOMER{ get; set; }
    public string NAME{ get; set; }
}
```

However, when I push a database update, I get a "Token Unknown" error.
This is due to how EF is creating the SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE "TB_CUSTOMER" (
    "ID_CUSTOMER" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    "NAME" BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_TB_CUSTOMER" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_CUSTOMER")
);
```

It seems `GENERATED BY` is a syntax brought for Firebird 3.0 (which I cannot use due to technical issues with third-party software). I couldn't find any information on whether I can use NET Core 3.1 (And FB.EF 7.5.0) with FB 2.5. Is it possible, or is it a lost cause?

If it is possible, how can I specify the version of FB the EF is supposed to expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment Firebird <3 is not supported. But if you carefully choose features, you can make it work. One option is to disable identity and [use sequence and trigger](https://github.com/cincuranet/FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient/blob/master/Provider/src/FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird/Extensions/FbPropertyBuilderExtensions.cs#L43).

Comment: Excellent! That was precisely what I was looking for! Also, since the database I am working with uses non-conventional EF Core nomenclature, I had to manually set the foreign keys with attribs...

Answer (score 2):

The `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` was indeed [introduced in Firebird 3](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity).

According to the discussion on the [firebird-net-provider Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-net-provider) in [Problems with boolean properties?](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-net-provider/c/iChkjvPXYDw/m/dpG1iDvhBgAJ), only Firebird 3 is supported for EF Core 3.1.

I'm not sure if there is an option that will suppress generating an identity column, but likely this wouldn't be the only compatibility issue.